# named starts but doesn't answer until reboot

Tags: arch-linux, dns, raspberry-pi, bind

I have a current arch linux arm running on raspberry-pi and bind 9.9.4.P2-1 from the community repository. 
I'm using this bind as a slave-nameserver for our internal network. 
I have enabled named using `systemctl enable named`.
When I reboot the raspberry pi the named doesn't answer for `dig stackexchange.com @xx.xx.xx.xx` and runs into a timeout. `systemctl status named` says named is active and all zones have been successfully loaded.
 If I simply login and issue `systemctl restart named` it provides the correct answer for `dig stackexchange.com @xx.xx.xx.xx`.

Comment: To provide some error messages, you could run named in foreground with enabled debugging switches `named -d 9 -f -u user`

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by editing : **/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/named.service**

Change :
*ExecStart=/usr/bin/named -f -u named*

To:
*ExecStart=/usr/bin/named -f -u root*

Of course it's not a very good solution ... but it works for me.